# Fetch and update with foreach loop

Tags: 7, database

I need to update the database. the code I am using was working, but after I have done some Drupal updates, it doesn't work anymore. I'm fetching data from table all is working but when I add code db_update, then it doesn't work, and also I cannot fetch all data, only which is not in db_update conditions is shown. Could someone help me with the code to fetch all data, then update it with conditions to another table?

```
$queryHomeTeams = db_select('krikis_home_page_today_results','k');
$queryHomeTeams->fields('k');
$results = $queryHomeTeams->execute()->fetchAll();

foreach ($results as $resu) {
  $home_t_id = $resu->h_id;
  $home_scr = $resu->home_score;
  $away_t_id = $resu->v_id;
  $away_scr = $resu->away_score;
  $gamestrt = $resu->gamestart;

 // Insert today match results.
 db_update('football_games')
   ->fields(array('h_score' => $home_scr,'v_score' => $away_scr,))
   ->condition('h_id', $home_t_id)
   ->condition('v_id', $away_t_id)
   ->condition('gamestart', $gamestrt)
   ->execute();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the db_select you still need to fetch the results after execute() with something like ->fetchAssoc() or ->fetchAll().

See the examples in the comments of the documentation: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7.x

Comment: Hey, I have tried both, ->fetchAssoc() or ->fetchAll() , but issue still exist. Cannot update database table with condition

Comment: So please provide more information as to what is going wrong. Did you debug the $results variable to see that it looks like with and without the fetch? Are you even entering the foreach loop?

Comment: Hey, yes I tried to debug. With fetchAll I can receive all data in array, with fetchAllAssoc cannot get anything. I can fetch all the neccessary data with foreach loop, but when I use in the same loop db_update then it starts to fetch only data which is not equals to db_updates conditions. But exactly what I need is to fetch data from table 'krikis_home_page_today_results' , compare 'h_id' ,'v_id', 'gamestart' data, and if data is same, update 'football_games' table with 'h_score',  'v_score'

Comment: The db_select is a different and independent operation from db_update, the select result does not change based on the db_update. You are probably getting some errors when executing the db_update. Try checking the php logs and drupal watchdog for more clues to help you.

Comment: I can see this error: PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column `dinis_winner`.`football_games`.`h_score` at row 1: UPDATE {football_games} SET h_score=:db_update_placeholder_0, v_score=:db_update_placeholder_1 WHERE (h_id = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (v_id = :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND (gamestart = :db_condition_placeholder_2) ;

Comment: Array ( [:db_update_placeholder_0] => [:db_update_placeholder_1] => [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 466 [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 1229 [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => 1561827600 ) in checkMatchResult() (line 142 of /home/dinis/domains/t-winner.com/public_html/today-match-results.php).

Comment: Thank you for your help, Error logs helped me, I just changed my database field type to varchar instead of integer. Now everything is working again